# Comparing Quarterly Sales from Q4 to Q1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table named Sales that looks like this:

```
 Year Quarter Sales
 2012    4     5000
 2013    1     6111
 2013    2     7222
```

And I'm trying to compare the sales increase from quarter to quarter, so I want to end up with something like this:

```
Q1 Q2 Sales Difference
 4  1      1111
 1  2      1111
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to compare Q4 of the previous year with Q1 of the next year.

I've set up an SQLFiddle with a similar table [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6913/9/0), along with the solution that works for quarters within the same year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
select a.Year, a.Quarter as Q1, ISNULL(b.Quarter, c.Quarter) as Q2, ISNULL(b.Sales, c.Sales) - a.Sales AS [Sales Increase]
from Sales a
left join Sales b on a.Quarter = b.Quarter - 1 and a.Year = b.Year
left join Sales c on a.Quarter = 4 and c.Quarter = 1 and a.Year = c.Year - 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62879/2) (though changing 2014 Q5 to Q1...)

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
WITH QuarterlySales AS (
    SELECT Sales.Quarter, Sales.Year, DateAdd(q,Sales.Quarter,CAST('01/01/'+CAST(YEAR AS CHAR(4)) AS DATE)) AS QDate
        , Sales
    FROM Sales)
SELECT b.[Quarter] as [Q1], a.[Quarter] AS [Q2], 
        a.Sales - b.Sales AS [Sales Increase]
FROM QuarterlySales a 
LEFT JOIN QuarterlySales b 
    ON a.[QDate] = DateAdd(q,1,b.[QDate])
```

Not sure if the performance on this is better or worse than @chrisb.  It does one less scan of the table but probably won't do as well with indexes.  I would be curious to see how it does on a larger example.

Answer (score 1):

I find that using a CTE helps with keeping your code organized and clean.  The messy part where you need to reformat numbers and match Q4 with the next year's Q1 can be handled there and your main query is simple.

```
with NewSales (QtrDate, DisplayDate, Year, Quarter, Sales) as (
    select
      Year - 0.25 + (Quarter / 4.0) as QtrDate,
      cast(Year as varchar(10)) + '-Q' + cast(Quarter as varchar(10)) as DisplayDate,
      Year, Quarter, Sales
    from
      @sales
)



select
  a.DisplayDate, a.Sales, 
  b.DisplayDate, b.Sales,
  b.Sales - a.Sales as SalesIncrease,
  (b.Sales / (a.Sales * 1.0)) - 1 as SalesPctIncrease

from
  NewSales a left outer join
    NewSales b on a.QtrDate + 0.25 = b.QtrDate

where
    a.Sales is not null and b.Sales is not null
```

I added a bit of flair (the bare minimum :) with the formatting of the quarters and the percentage calculation, you can use these examples to help customize the output as you'd like.